# VHDL convert statement to loop problem

Tags: vhdl

I am new to vhdl. Is there a way to shorten the following code using loops:

```
v_hold := buff(row)(i)(0) & buff(row)(i)(1) & buff(row)(i)(2) & buff(row)(i)(3) &
                     buff(row)(i)(4) & buff(row)(i)(5) & buff(row)(i)(6) & buff(row)(i)(7) &
                     buff(row)(i)(8) & buff(row)(i)(9) & buff(row)(i)(10) & buff(row)(i)(11) &
                     buff(row)(i)(12) & buff(row)(i)(13) & buff(row)(i)(14) & buff(row)(i)(15) &
                     buff(row)(i)(16) & buff(row)(i)(17) & buff(row)(i)(18) & buff(row)(i)(19) &
                     buff(row)(i)(20) & buff(row)(i)(21) & buff(row)(i)(22) & buff(row)(i)(23) &
                     buff(row)(i)(24) & buff(row)(i)(25) & buff(row)(i)(26) & buff(row)(i)(27) &
                     buff(row)(i)(28) & buff(row)(i)(29) & buff(row)(i)(30) & buff(row)(i)(31) &
                     buff(row)(i)(32) & buff(row)(i)(33) & buff(row)(i)(34) & buff(row)(i)(35) &
                     buff(row)(i)(36) & buff(row)(i)(37) & buff(row)(i)(38) & buff(row)(i)(39) &
                     buff(row)(i)(40) & buff(row)(i)(41) & buff(row)(i)(42) & buff(row)(i)(43) &
                     buff(row)(i)(44) & buff(row)(i)(45) & buff(row)(i)(46) & buff(row)(i)(47) &
                     buff(row)(i)(48) & buff(row)(i)(49) & buff(row)(i)(50) & buff(row)(i)(51) &
                     buff(row)(i)(52) & buff(row)(i)(53) & buff(row)(i)(54) & buff(row)(i)(55) &
                     buff(row)(i)(56) & buff(row)(i)(57) & buff(row)(i)(58) & buff(row)(i)(59) &
                     buff(row)(i)(60) & buff(row)(i)(61) & buff(row)(i)(62) & buff(row)(i)(63));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply write `buff(row)(i)(0 to 63)`